# Unit test spyOn is never called angular factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-factory

I am trying to write a unit test for a angular factory:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    var factoryName = 'UserFactory';
    var components = ['ProductFactory', '$state'];

    var factory = function (ProductFactory, $state) {

        var viewState = function(view, data) {
            if(data.access[view] === true) {
                return;
            }
            else {                
                $state.go('notAuth');
            }
        };

        return {
            viewState: viewState
        };
    };

    components.push(factory);

    return {
        name: factoryName,
        component: components
    };
});
```

I have the following unit test:

```
define(['require', 'angular-mocks'], function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');

    describe('<-- UserFactory Spec ------>', function () {

        var scope, $httpBackend, userFactory;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('UserFactory'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _UserFactory_) {
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            userFactory = _UserFactory_;
            spyOn(userFactory, 'viewState').and.returnValue({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith',access:'read'});
            scope.$apply();
        }));


        it('method viewState() was called', function () {
            expect(userFactory.viewState).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

However i see the following error:

```
Expected spy viewState to have been called.
```

Comment: I don't see where `viewState` *is* called though? You define it, but you don't call it? e.g I see no `ProductFactory.viewState()`

Comment: @MattLishman - ah! that would help, where is the best place to call it? I am trying it now within the it statement

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how to test this factory (that, or I misunderstand your code). If you were testing a controller, I would expect you to test it was called. if you are testing a factory, I would expect you to test it was defined and then test the way it works. What exactly is it you are trying to test?

Comment: @MattLishman - i want to test the way it works. I want to test viewState and the if/else condition

Comment: @MattLishman - for example. i would like to test that $state.go('notAuth'); is called if the if condition is not met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to test the implementation of the `viewState` function, you will need to call it in your test. You also don't need to test it was called (because the source code doesn't test it).

You don't need to mock it out, that defeats the purpose of testing it. This is because a mock **does not** call through to the actual implementation, unless you tell it to but you don't need that here.

Your test should look something like this:

```
describe('<-- UserFactory Spec ------>', function () {

    var userFactory;
    var $state = {
        go: function(){}
    };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('UserFactory'));

    // Set the $state injectable to be our mocked out $state (only for this test)
    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('$state', $state);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_UserFactory_) {
        userFactory = _UserFactory_;

        // Mock out the $state.go method
        spyOn($state, 'go'); 
    }));


    it('should redirect to the notAuth state', function () {
        // Call the method we are testing
        userFactory.viewState(/** pass in some conditions to make it call $state.go**/);
        expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('notAuth');
    });
});
```

I have done a few things here:

- Removed $scope, you don't need it here.
- Mocked out the `$state.go function` - so we can test it was called.
- Called `userFactory.viewState()` - so we can test the function.
- Removed your mock of `viewState()` - so we can test the actual implementation.

To test that it is calling this method correctly, you can use some `console.logs`.

```
var viewState = function(view, data) {
    console.log('View ', view);
    console.log('Data ', data);
    console.log(data.access[view]);
    console.log(data.access[view] === true);
    if(data.access[view] === true) {
        return;
    }
    else {                
        $state.go('notAuth');
    }
};
```

Now just check that all the console logs are what you expect.

---

P.S I can't test this code so it might not be 100%, but this is the general gist.

Comment: Thanks, tried the above, get this error: Information:    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$state.go = jasmine.createSpy('go')')

Comment: @OamPsy Oops, I forgot to define `$state` as an object. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, tried edit, see Information: Expected spy go to have been called. Im using Jasmine 2.0... if thats any use

Comment: Make sure you are passing in something that will call the spy. e.g `viewState(0, {access: [false]})`

Comment: Hmm, ive triple checked, and copied and pasted the exact JSON from what the server sends, i see:  Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'notAuth' ] but it was never called. Thats when i add spyOn(userFactory, 'viewState') in my beforeEach

Comment: If i remove spyOn(userFactory, 'viewState') from my beforeEach i get error: Error: Could not resolve 'notAuth' from state ''

Comment: @OamPsy Added a way to debug to my answer. You will just have to debug the function is being called correctly now. Use the example parameters I gave, that is the simplest way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! My console.logs seem perfect. And i have placed console.log(1) inside if and console.log(2) in else... 1 is never logged, always 2! So the code is right.. But still seeing Error: Could not resolve 'notAuth' from state ''

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to inject `$state` correctly. To use a mocked out injectable you need to tell the provider that you want to use it. I have edited my code. The error you are getting is because it is trying to inject the real `$state` object, not your mocked out one.